# Summing a list of integers then calculate the average

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the sum of element in my 2D list.
but I get the error:

```
    sum_stu1 += sum(student)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

This is my full program: The actual program will be getting elements using user input for current list is for testing.

```
def average(x):
    sum_stu1 = 0
    for student in student_list:
        sum_stu1 += sum(student)
        return sum_stu1

student1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
student2 = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
student3 = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
student4 = [40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
student5 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

student_list = [
    [student1],
    [student2],
    [student3],
    [student4],
    [student5]
]

average(student_list)
```

My next line of thought once this part is resolved is:

```
for student in student_list:
    sum_stu1 += sum(student) / 5
```

to calculate the average as there is a max of 5 inputs - would this be right?

Comment: Consider using Python's [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module to do these kinds of computations if you are unsure how to do them.

Comment: Why is `student_list` a list of lists of lists of grades, instead of a list of lists of grades?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error is caused by writing `[student1]` instead of just `student1`, etc., and fixing this won't help anyone calculate the average of a list of integers.

Comment: There is an additional error: the indentation of `return sum_stu1`

Answer (score 2):

Use `statistics.mean` to compute the mean of a given list, and make sure that you're iterating over a list of lists instead of wrapping each list in another list.  Also, note that if you have a function that computes the average of a list (whether it's `statistics.mean` or one you write yourself), you probably want to pass it the grades for *one* student at a time; if you pass it the whole student list and then iterate over the list, you'll only get the *first* student.

Creating the `student1` etc variables makes this code unnecessarily confusing; just create the list of lists directly and then iterate over it:

```
from statistics import mean

students = [
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    [30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
    [40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
    [50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
]

for student in students:
    print(mean(student))
```

prints:

```
30
40
50
60
70
```

If you wanted to write your own average function that imitates `statistics.mean` it would be simply:

```
def average(student):
    return sum(student) / len(student)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. We have to specifically use a function so thanks for including that. Unfortunately I get the error:    return sum(student) / len(student)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

*** I am running the following code: ***

from statistics import mean

def average(student):
    return sum(student) / len(student)

students = [
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    [30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
    [40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
    [50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
]

print(average(students))

Comment: You're repeating the exact same mistake of passing the entire list to `average` instead of averaging each student individually.  You should be able to use the `average` function exactly the same way I used `statistics.mean` -- if you look at the code I provided you will note that I do **not** call `mean(students)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider restructuring your data into a dictionary:

```
from statistics import mean

students = {
    'student1': {
        'scores': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    },
    'student2': {
        'scores': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    },
    'student3': {
        'scores': [30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
    },
    'student4': {
        'scores': [40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
    },
    'student5': {
        'scores': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
    }
}

for student, data in students.items():
    students[student]['avg'] = mean(data['scores'])

print(students)
```

Output:

```
{
    'student1': {
        'scores': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 
        'avg': 30
    }, 
    'student2': {
        'scores': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 
        'avg': 40
    }, 
    'student3': {
        'scores': [30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 
        'avg': 50
    }, 
    'student4': {
        'scores': [40, 50, 60, 70, 80], 
        'avg': 60
    }, 
    'student5': {
        'scores': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90], 
        'avg': 70
    }
}
```

This allows for much more scalability, rather than so much hard coding...

Comment: Thanks for this. This would be the ideal output for my program, however I'm required to create and use an averaging function

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong with the code

The correct code should look like this:

```
def average(x):
    sum_stu1 = 0
    for student in x:
        sum_stu1 += sum(student)
    return sum_stu1


student1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
student2 = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
student3 = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
student4 = [40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
student5 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

student_list = [
    student1,
    student2,
    student3,
    student4,
    student5
]

print(average(student_list))
```

ALSO NOTE THAT THIS IS NOT THE BEST APPROACH RATHER SURVES AS A CORRECTION TO YOUR CODE SYNTAX

Ok, first in your function `average()`, in the `for..loop` you used `student_list` instead of the argument **x** passed

Also, the `return` statement is inside the `for..loop`

Then, the main problem, you are creating a list of a list of a list in the variable `student_list`.
The variable `student1` to `student5` are already of type list so you do not need to put in the square brackets when creating another list from them.

Thats where the error came from, the `student` in the `for..loop` is given the value of a list of a list instead of just a list

Feel free to ask any questions! Hope I helped

Comment: Hi thanks so much for this! Helped me understand the errors. Unfortunately although not the best approach -they've specifically asked to use functions in our program :( 

I was able to make the function average work:

def average(x):
    sum_stu1 = 0
    for student in x:
        for course in student:
            sum_stu1 += sum(student) /5
            return sum_stu1

print(average(student_list))

However it only takes the first list of the student_list, is there a way I can pass it through the whole list and produce an average for all 5 elements

Comment: Check on your indentation, am assuming you've put the return statement in the wrong place.